# Session is not kept/destroyed when i navigate to other pages

Tags: php

Good day.SO i am having an issue in that, when i create a session via a login and a user is authenticated, once i leave that page to say a different page, i am not whether the session is destroyed or not created in the first place, i require this page to hold the session so i can be able to query the users email from it, and use it to query the database to determine the username.

This is my submit.php, called once the user clicks login on the page.

```
  <?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password =$_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE EMAIL='$email' AND ENCRYPTEDPWD='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header("Location: Landing page.php"); 
    exit();
    }
    else{
        header("Location: customerportal.php?login=invalid");   
        exit(); 
        }
    }


?>
```

it redirects to the next page, the landing page.
This page should check email from the session, and then display a username.

```
<?php
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL='$email';";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($resultCheck > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo $row['username'];                  
                }               
            }

            else{
                echo "No User.";
            }

            ?>
```

Please help.

Comment: `Landing page.php`? why there is space?

Comment: in landing page you need to assign value from `$_SESSION['email']` to `$email` instead of `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the landing page in below line:-

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;// here you are assigning to SESSION
```

It needs to be:-

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];//assign value from SESSION to variable
```

***So code needs to be like this:-***

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL='$email'";
```

***Note:-*** Your code is wide-open for `SQL INJECTION`. Try to use `prepared statements` to prevent it.

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! it worked, inverting the landing page session set

Comment: @AshleyNesh  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

In your landing page, invert the line after session_start(): You are assigning an empty variable to overwrite your already saved session variable

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

If your query causes you problems after that, try concatenating $email

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL='".$email."';";
```

Comment: OP 's query is correct, concatenation only required if you are using `'` quotes , with `"` is not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I suggested it because it sometimes used to cause me problems, especially when mail validation is not operated at character level. This leaves it vulnerable to using quoting characters inside the email, thus breaking the query

Comment: this will not give excepted output as now value is `.$email.` (note `.`) instead of `$email`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. fixed it

Comment: quotes along with `.` in `".$email."` is not required actually. what OP has is correct. double quotes outside will parse variable perfectly. Also `;` is unnecessary too. (will not create an issue but unnecessary)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! it worked, inverting the landing page session set